# I cannot check the version of mysql being installed

Tags: mysql, logging, command-line, xampp, version

I cannot check the version of mysql being installed.

That is very crazy, but there is literally no solution on the internet which would allow me to check the version of mysql being installed. That is very oppressing, because something that should be very very easy to do takes so much effort from me.

So, I have **xampp** installed.

The first approach which I tried is to go to the `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` folder and try out all the possible commands like `mysql -v`, `mysql --v`, `mysql --version`, `mysql -version` and so on and neither of these commands did work.

Also I tried to go to **xampp** control panel, but I did not find the version of mysql there.

If you need something else in order to help me diagnose the issue, please, let me know.

Thank you.

Here is the error which I am getting when trying to run the command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -V
'c:\xampp\mysql\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

At the same time here is my Control Panel at the time I run the command:
[image]

And here is what I see when I try to run the select statement

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>select version();
'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: ```select version();``` is an SQL command. Run the ```mysql``` command processor first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you getting an error message? If so, you probably haven't started MySQL.

Make sure you start MySQL from the xampp control panel, then

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.28-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question, could you, please, have a look at it.

Comment: Does the following result mean that I have MariaDB of the version 10.1.37?`C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)`

Comment: @oobarbazanoo Yes, it is version 10.1.37.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest is a simple SQL call.

```
select version();
```

which should give you something like

```
MariaDB [stackex]> select version();
+--------------------------+
| version()                |
+--------------------------+
| 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [stackex]>
```

**Note:** My Raspbian systems all run MariaDB rather than MySQL but you'll get similar results.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question, could you, please, have a look at it.

Comment: I found the other answer to be acceptable for my problem. Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1):

Go on installed path for example: C:\xampp
There is a txt file named readme_en.txt you can see all details you want

```
  + Apache 2.4.41
  + MariaDB 10.4.11
  + PHP 7.4.2 (VC15 X86 64bit thread safe) + PEAR
  + phpMyAdmin 5.0.1
  + OpenSSL 1.1.0g
  + ADOdb 518a
  + Mercury Mail Transport System v4.63 (not included in the portable version)
  + FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41 (not included in the portable version)
  + Webalizer 2.23-04 (not included in the portable version)
  + Strawberry Perl 5.16.3.1 Portable
  + Tomcat 7.0.99
  + XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.2.4.
  + XAMPP mailToDisk 1.0 (write emails via PHP on local disk in <xampp>\mailoutput. Activated in the php.ini as mail default.)
```

Also you can open XAMPP Control Panel, hit on the "Help" button and then "View ReadMe".

The same file will open

Answer (score -1):

You typed the command incorrectly
Use this:

```
C:\xampp>c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -V
```

Result:

```
c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.19-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
```